# Cakephp: passing multiple selectbox options in the url

Tags: cakephp, select

i'm stuck again.
i NEED to pass search form variable in the url (GET).
If i make a dropdown in the form a multiple select dropdown, i cant seem to pass the array of selections.

when i paas the argument the url looks like this:
http://localhost/cakephp/applicants/index/Search.experiences:Array

and in my controller, i try access it like this:
$keywords = $this->passedArgs['Search.experiences'];

I'm not convinced the actual array id being passed into the url, looks like it's just the word 'Array' that gets passed.

is there any way i can do this?

Thanks,
Vauneen

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to `implode` your `Search.experiences` on something like a comma and then, in your controller do an `explode` on a comma to access the data.

Comment: you mean implode before using it in the url?

Comment: Correct. That way you retain the original data instead of having the array being typecasted into 'Array'